# Assistance with reshaping intensive longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, reshape, longitudinal

Apologies if I'm not posting correctly. I'm new to R and this is my first post to stackoverflow. I've read as much as can to find a solution to my problem, but haven't been able to find something I can use.

I have some intensive longitudinal data that I'm trying to reshape. Currently it is in wide format and looks something like this:

```
Participant   D1_1_1   D1_1_2   D1_1_3   D1_1_4    D2_1_1   D2_1_2  etc...
P1               6        2        3        5        1         2
P2               4        9        3        6        4         1
P3               7        4        2        8        1         1
P4               1        5        1        1        6         7 
P5               2        0        8        2        1         4
etc..
```

The column variables refer to responses to a specific survey item, made on a particular day, at a particular times throughout the day.

So:

D1_1_1 = day 1, time 1, item 1

D1_1_2 = day 1, time 1, item 2

...

D4_3_7 = day4, time 3, item 7

In total, the data I have covers:
60 participants who have responded to 11 items, 4 times in a day, for 10 days (a total of 440 data points per participant).

I'm looking to get help on being able to manipulate this effectively into long format, so it could look, for example, like this:

```
Participant     Day     time    item 1   item 2 ... item 11
P1               1        1        6        2
P1               1        2        X        X
P1               1        3        X        X
P1               1        4        X        X
P1               2        1        1        4
etc..
```

Where X is the participant's response to a given survey item, on a particular day, at a particular time.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ronak's answer works perfectly but there's no need to use `extract`: `pivot_longer` can already break the column into several ones:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Participant, names_to = c("day", "time", "item"), 
               names_pattern = "(D\\d)_(\\d)_(\\d)") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value, names_prefix = "Item")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#>    Participant day   time  Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
#>    <fct>       <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 P1          D1    1         6     2     3     5
#>  2 P1          D2    1         1     2    NA    NA
#>  3 P2          D1    1         4     9     3     6
#>  4 P2          D2    1         4     1    NA    NA
#>  5 P3          D1    1         7     4     2     8
#>  6 P3          D2    1         1     1    NA    NA
#>  7 P4          D1    1         1     5     1     1
#>  8 P4          D2    1         6     7    NA    NA
#>  9 P5          D1    1         2     0     8     2
#> 10 P5          D2    1         1     4    NA    NA
```

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(Participant = structure(1:5, .Label = c("P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), class = "factor"), D1_1_1 = c(6L, 4L, 
7L, 1L, 2L), D1_1_2 = c(2L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 0L), D1_1_3 = c(3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 8L), D1_1_4 = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L), D2_1_1 = c(1L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 1L), D2_1_2 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir.

I had some trouble getting it to work, but eventually it did. 
I think the \\d parts only work for numbers 0-9, so it wasn't capturing item 10 and 11.
I changed these to letters X and Y, and used //w instead--this seemed to work for me. 

Thank you for helping me :) Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with `pivot_longer` + `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, cols = -Participant, names_to = c("Day", "Time", "Item"), 
                 names_pattern = "D(\\d+)_(\\d+)_(\\d+)") %>%
    mutate(Item = paste0("Item",Item)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 10 x 7
#   Participant Day   Time  Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
#   <fct>       <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 P1          1     1         6     2     3     5
# 2 P1          2     1         1     2    NA    NA
# 3 P2          1     1         4     9     3     6
# 4 P2          2     1         4     1    NA    NA
# 5 P3          1     1         7     4     2     8
# 6 P3          2     1         1     1    NA    NA
# 7 P4          1     1         1     5     1     1
# 8 P4          2     1         6     7    NA    NA
# 9 P5          1     1         2     0     8     2
#10 P5          2     1         1     4    NA    NA
```

---

We can also use `extract` using the same pattern as `names_pattern` in `pivot_longer`

```
pivot_longer(df, cols = -Participant) %>%
     extract(name, into = c("Day", "Time", "Item"), 
             regex = "D(\\d+)_(\\d+)_(\\d+)") %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = value)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Participant = structure(1:5, .Label = c("P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), class = "factor"), D1_1_1 = c(6L, 4L, 
7L, 1L, 2L), D1_1_2 = c(2L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 0L), D1_1_3 = c(3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 8L), D1_1_4 = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L), D2_1_1 = c(1L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 1L), D2_1_2 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```